# This is a comparison between non-normal samples of different sizes?

Tags: statistical-significance, nonparametric, skewness, median, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have **16 types of experiments** (a matrix of 4 conditions and 4 bacterial strains).
Each **experiment type** is composed by a variable number of **samples** (4-8).
Each **sample** is made of a variable number of **data points** (50-300).
When plotted, each sample gives rise to a non-normal distribution, heavily skewed to large values.
I have calculated the median of each sample (as the median is a better descriptor for skewed distributions). Do i need the standard deviation of this median?
How can I determine the average value of a given experiment type?- Could it be as simple the mean of the medians? 
How can I assess the statistical significance between these 16 types of experiments? Could a Mann-Whitney test do the trick?

Example:

Cell type X, Condition A
-Sample 1-300 data points Mean 28.87    median 14.62
-Sample 2-258 data points Mean 35.71    median 14.75
-Sample 3-365 data points mean 24.53    median 13.81
-Sample 4-244 data points mean 28.60    median 18.70

*all heavily skewed histograms*.
-Average mean 29.43, average median 15.47- Is this valid?- Do I get here the standard error of the median (i.e. 1.2533 × SE)?
-Can I compare the value of 15.47 to the average median of a different type of experiment? How can I tell if the difference is significant?. I would like to compare a given cell (cell A) among 4 different conditions.

Many thanks for reading!

Comment: If your interest lies specifically in the population mean (given *How can I determine the average value of a given experiment type?*), then you have two main choices; you can either estimate the mean by using ... well, *means*, or you can make a parametric assumption and use whatever reasonably efficient estimator of the mean you have in that situation (which in some situations could be in part based on a function of a sample median but usually that won't be your best choice conditional on typical distribution models for heavily skewed population distributions). On the other hand ... ctd

Comment: ... if by "average value" you meant something else (such as population median) then you'd need to be clearer about that; the distinction between the population quantity you care to measure and what may be good ways to estimate it from a sample can be important. If possible, can you show a typical histogram as well as one of the log-values (at least if they're all positive)? It's hard to discern much from the difference between averages of means and averages of medians (other than it's probably pretty right skew, as you already said is the case). ... ctd

Comment: ... You should clarify what it is you want to find out, what question you'd like to answer (the one you wanted an answer to before you looked at the data!).  Whatever that is, you probably won't want to average medians.